# How to display DELETE and EDIT in appbar on hold of a list item in List View?

Tags: dart, flutter, crud

I am building a simple todo app. I would like to display a edit and delete button in the appbar when user holds on a todo in a ListView. How do I change the appbar and ListView item style like turn background color red.

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the event through the `GestureDetector` on a `ListItem`, you can do something like this:

```
      .......
       body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: id == null ? 0 : id.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new GestureDetector( //You need to make my child interactive
              onTap: () => _selectedItem(id[index]),
              child: new Card( //I am the clickable child
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(id[index]),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
       ....
```

You can then change color and call the `Appbar` in method `_selectedItem(id[index])`